# How do I test multiple parallel threads per-user in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMeter to simulate a user running our Android app. This app has several background threads that poll different services at different intervals. I'd like to test a large number of these types of users. Is there a way to do that in JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

If "different intervals" come into play the only solution I can think of is using different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) for representing different services consumers as due to JMeter's threads model all [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) inside a single Thread Group will act at a speed of the "slowest" sampler and given the application has "background" services these calls need to be non-blocking.

There are other approaches like using [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller), [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide), etc. but they fall under the aforementioned limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured it out. I use a combination of Parallel Controller, and nested within those are Loop Controllers with a Flow Control Action that pauses for the right number of seconds. I'll leave this question open for a bit in case anyone has a better recommendation.

See: https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md